# C# Lambda expressions with Classes

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am reading a csv with a list of students - Name, Surname, ClassLeader, Grade,Subject, Score.

I want to add a new student if he doesn't exist or only add the Subject and Score if the student exists in the list. Code below:

```
   class School
    {
        private int[] Grades = new int[5] { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
        public List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
        private HashSet<string> AllSubjects = new HashSet<string>();

        public School()
        {

        }

        public void CreateStudents()
        {                
            List<string[]> storedCSVData = CSVHelper.ReadCSV();
            //int index = 0;

            foreach(string[] lineItem in storedCSVData)
            {
                //index++;
                //if ((index % 6) != 0)
                //    continue;
                string fullName = lineItem[0] + " " + lineItem[1];

                int i = Students.IndexOf(x =>  
                x.GetFullName().Contains(fullName));

                    if(i >= 0){
                    Students[i].SubjectScore.Add(lineItem[4], 

                    Convert.ToDouble(lineItem[5]));
                        continue;
                    }                         

                    Student storedStudent = new Student(lineItem[0],
                                                        lineItem[1],
                                                        lineItem[2] == "Yes" 
                                                        `? true : false,`

                   Convert.ToInt32(lineItem[3]));

                    Students.Add(storedStudent);

            }

            foreach(Student s in Students)
            Console.WriteLine(s.GetFullName());

        }
    }
```

}

In student class:

```
    class Student : Person
    {
        private bool ClassLeader = false;
        private int Grade = 0;
        public Dictionary<string, double> SubjectScore = new 
                                          Dictionary<string, double>();


        public Student(string name, string surname, bool classLeader, int 
                       grade)
        {
            Name = name;
            Surname = surname;
            ClassLeader = classLeader;
            Grade = grade;
        }

        public string GetFullName()
        {
            return Name + " " + Surname;
        }


    }
```

I keep getting an error that says Cannot convert lambda expression of type 'Student' because it is not a delegate type.

Can someone please help with this, I'm currently lost.

Comment: I would start with letting us know which line gives you such error. :)

Comment: My apologies. Under class School the method CreateStudents() the line: int i = Students.IndexOf(x =>  x.GetFullName().Contains(fullName));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using reference to `Student`, searching it in list and then retrieving its `index` doesn't make sense.
You are using `Student` instance anyway, so use LINQ's `FirstOrDefault` and retrieve object you are trying to modify (in this case, to change the `SubjectScore`).

You'd rather:

```
foreach(string[] lineItem in storedCSVData)
{

    string fullName = lineItem[0] + " " + lineItem[1];

    //Get student instance instead of index, since you would use it anyway
    Student student = Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.GetFullName().Contains(fullName));

    //If there is no result, FirstOrDefault returns 'null'
    if(student != null)
    {
        //Add using refernce instead of using index
        student.SubjectScore.Add(
            lineItem[4], 
            Convert.ToDouble(lineItem[5]));
        continue;
    }                         

    Student storedStudent = new Student(lineItem[0],
                                        lineItem[1],
                                        lineItem[2] == "Yes" ? true : false,
                                        Convert.ToInt32(lineItem[3]));

    Students.Add(storedStudent);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has solved the problem. I was stuck on this for more than a week. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are passing the Lambda expression for an [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) method which only supports an Item instead of Lambda. Try to get the `Student` using Lambda and use the `Student` to get the index.

```
Student student = Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetFullName().Contains(fullName));
int i = Students.IndexOf(student);
```